# . (Kali) I’m stuck

Tags: command-line, kali-linux, networkmanager

I downloaded the latest version on my 2012 mac, and flashed it onto a usb with etcher, it booted just fine, and everything seemed okay, but then I went to proxy and a popup appeared: Alert! Network manager is missing! Call your system provider”

I tried looking for it, tried commands, heck I even tried to hack myself, but while it could scan and see networks in terminal, it would not connect in any way.

Webdav also failed. Wifi hotspot failed. Ethernet, nothing.
Bluetooth? Option to turn it on was greyed out.

So what should I do?

Comment: do not use kali, it is a tool for experts and not meant to be used as a general use distribution .... download something like Linux Mint instead

Comment: See https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

Comment: Not any linux is for everybody. Installed recently an anti "beta" and it took me to put wifi working in my particular office environment, and I am an experienced professional

Answer (score 6):

I suggest yhou read the link @DK Bose shared in the comments.

https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux

The very first line of the page explains what Kali is and who it is for.

> Kali Linux is specifically geared to meet the requirements of professional penetration testing and security auditing.

Your post is titled "Tried Linux for the first time". This suggests you are new to Linux and a beginner. This is OKAY! Every single member here was once a beginner; everyone must start somewhere. We welcome and encourage you!

You have unfortunately chosen a distribution that to the general public appears "fashionable" and "sexy"; but is actually a VERY BAD CHOICE to learn UNIX. Kali is designed for some very specific purposes and to achieve this it violates many best-practices.

I suggest you consider Linux Mint, Ubuntu, or another general purpose standard operating system.

Comment: Thank you, you're indeed right. Kali-Linux appears sexy, edgy, and I admit I got drawn in, but has led to be very specific in it's scope of application.

Comment: No problem. I come from very personal experience. It looks cool; but I can't get a damned thing done that isn't pen-testing type of work. :)